# Data in data tab and preview tab is not matching?

Tags: reporting-services

In my report I m able to see all my data when running query in data tab...but in preview i see a blank page...I have four parameters in my query..

I tried deleting .data files also...no luck..
any suggestions are at great help??

Answer (score 0):

Apologies in advance if this is a dumb suggestion - have you tried clicking on the `View Report` button in the Preview tab?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a table on your report that is bound to your dataset?

Go to the properties for the table (right-click square in upper left corner of table and choose Properties) and make sure the Visibility is set to "Visible."